# Is it valid if magento 2 theme created with CSS3?

Tags: magento2, css, less-css, luma-theme

My question is related to this general Topic like if i have not much knowledge about of less css and i have created a custom theme by using **CSS3** so is it valid or not valid in term of validation ?

Can i use CSS3 for creating of theme rather than less style ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course: CSS and CSS3, HTML and HTML5, you can confirm this and view more detail in the official [Frontend Developer Guide](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/bk-frontend-dev-guide.html)